# Analyzing and understanding a foreign AWS Setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I was given read only access to a customer's AWS account and asked to understand and get familiar with their architecture.

I started off by exploring the different services and the only thing that I could find that was "populated" was the S3 service, where I noticed they have a bunch of buckets. I couldn't find anything under EC2 nor any DB's at RDS.

Is this a permissions issue with my account or is there another approach I should be using to get familiar with their architecture?

Comment: AWS is very region centric. For most services, you need to select the region that you want to work in. Ask them which regions they are using. I would just go to the AWS EC2 console and then click thru all of the regions and make note of each region they have services (most likely only one or two unless they are a global company).

Comment: @JohnHanley that was it! i switched a few regions and found them! thank you very much!